# Getting a rasterized object from irregular lat and long data

Tags: raster, r, latitude-longitude, sp, rgdal

I have a dataframe (I've named it ozone2raster) with latitude and longitude points, and values for ozone concentration that I want to use for making a rasterized map. The dimensions of this dataframe are 3 cols, and 414 rows. The lat and lon are supposed to be at the centers of 12x12 kilometer grids. I've been trying several methods, but the limitation seems to be that my lat and lon are not regularly spaced. For example, I tried using this function:

```
rasterFromXYZ(ozone2raster)
```

And got this error:

> Error in rasterFromXYZ(ozone2raster) : x cell sizes are not regular

After that, I tried a slightly more complicated code.

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)

pts <- ozone2raster
coordinates(pts)=~x+y
proj4string(pts)=CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
pts = spTransform(pts,CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
gridded(pts) = TRUE ### NOT WORKING HERE!!!
r = raster(pts)
projection(r) = CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
plot(r)
```

It worked up until the line with the code `gridded(pts) = TRUE` and gave me this error:

> suggested tolerance minimum: 0.142857
> Error in points2grid(points, tolerance, round) : dimension 1 : coordinate intervals are not constant

At this point I really have no idea what to do. I've seen several similar questions on here, but I haven't been able to get any of them to work for my dataframe.

Comment: Very difficult to help without seeing the data and/or some illustration (e.g. a plot of the points). You also need be clear about in *which CRS* the points are "regular".